# Publish Standalone ASP.NET Core 1.0 Application

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an ASP.NET Core Application with REST apis. In development in VS Studio 2015 I just Run application like an executable or directly from command-line with dotnet run and works very fine. According to my config, it runs at port 5000:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseUrls("http://*:1000", "https://*:1234", "http://0.0.0.0:5000")
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

I have no problem sending my proper GET requests (with Basic Authorization and resolved by a Custom Middleware class) when the application is running with Kestrel. But when I choose "IIExpress" in VS2015 and run (at different and random port, let's say http://localhost:60136) it doesn't work, when I try to send any request (now to that port 60136) it returns an OPTIONS 401. Apparently, is ignoring my Custom Middleware.

Because of that I need to publish this in my Windows Server 2012, I tough that I could avoid using IIS, but some docs and comments point me to don't use Kestrel directly...

Also, I generated the app with this command:

```
dotnet publish -f netcoreapp1.0 -c release
```

But, there's no executables!

Is there any way to run this application in my server as I do in dev ?
Or is there a way to install it properly with IIS?

Comment: There seem to be an opened feed on Github describing your exact issue. That could be of help. https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/77

Comment: According to some comments, I should run like this: `dotnet app.dll`, but I got this: `The targeted framework { 'Microsoft.NETCore.App': '1.0.0' } was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
      1.0.0-rc2-3002702
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.0'.`

Comment: I resolved by installing .NET Core from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#winserverhost , but now I got this: `Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package:
 'Dapper', version: '1.50.2', path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Dapper.dll'`
I'm having a lot of deploy problems for something that supposes to be standalone or portable... :/

Comment: I just resolved myself: I was running in the wrong directory. I have to run dotnet app.dll inside publish directory

Comment: @Mr_LinDowsMac please post your solution and mark it as answer so anyone can use it :D